# ¿Cargar username PrimaryKey en url?

Tags: mysql, angularjs, laravel, url, rutas

Buenas noches.

Tengo una duda simple, estoy tratando de que me liste una lista de variables provenientes de una bd MYSQL mediante su primery key.

Hasta aqui todo facil, lo complicado viene es que mi ruta esta asi

```
projectName.com/primaryKey
```

Pero deseo que sea asi

```
primaryKey.projectName.com
```

Existe o conocen alguna forma de lograr esto

Comment: Para laravel tienes la opción [Sub-Domain Routing](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#route-group-sub-domain-routing)

Comment: puedes agregar esto como respuesta para colocarla como la respuesta correcta.. Gracias?

Comment: Está bien , respuesta agregada. Espero haya ayudado, Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para estos detalles, `laravel` cuenta con [Sub-Domain Routing](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#route-group-sub-domain-routing) que hace el enrutamiento a subdominios , *Ejem*

```
Route::domain('{primaryKey}.myapp.com')->group(function () {
    /**  Defines tus demás rutas**/
});
```